# AngularJS: Go to a state only if that state has not transitioned to before

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

I have the following state in routes.js :

```
.state('showorderflow', {
    url: "#",
    templateUrl: '/assets/views/tvx/selection.html',
    controller: 'tvxChannelSelectCtrl'
})
```

and in my html I have the following code:

```
<a class="click-to-select" href="#"
    ng-click="packBtnClick($event)"> Click to order </a>
```

and my controller looks like this:

```
$scope.packBtnClick = function ($e) {
    $state.go('showorderflow');
    // do something else. 
}
```

I want to go to the state `showorderflow` only if it hasn't been transitioned to before. How can I do that?

Comment: Set a flag on the rootScope or on a service as soon as `tvxChannelSelectCtrl` loads. Then check that flag before you call `$state.go('showorderflow');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a controller say `GlobalController` in your `body` or `html` tag so that its scope is available throughout your pages (trying to prevent use of `$rootScope`). Now, in the `GlobalController` you can add a listener for state change:

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(e, toState) {
    if (toState.name === 'showorderflow') {
        // Use a key "hasBeenTransitionedBeforeFoo" to check if the user is already transitioned to that state before
        if (toState.hasBeenTransitionedBeforeFoo) {
            // If yes, then prevent the navigation
            e.preventDefault();
            return;
        }

        // Otherwise mark it as true on first time transition
        toState.hasBeenTransitionedBeforeFoo = true;
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you can register the same callback in the `run` block of your app

```
myApp.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(e, toState) {
        // same code goes here
    });
}]);
```